# jQuery draggable sortable input elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I use the jQuery UI library to drag and sort elements: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable
This works fine but I can't drag input elements such as a textarea. These textarea's are disabled so no need to be able to write in them.
I googled around a bit and noticed that I ain't the only one with this problem. There are some semi-solutions for this but they are all dated it seems. (jQuery develops quickly).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

HTML:

```
<div class="sortable-wrapper">
<ul id="sortable-list">
<div class="ui-state-default">
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( "#sortable-list" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable-list" ).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed something odd. As I said, I've disabled the textarea's, yet if I don't do this and add this: $("#aaa").draggable({ cancel: null }); ...it drags

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide some code for me if I should be able to help you.

(Note: If you are trying to drag the item while grabbing the textarea you should implement some switch to turn selection on/off. I would suggest a different approach where you can always edit the textarea by clicking inside. For sorting I would use a handle to grab.)

The jQuery sortable works with lists, that is `<ul>` and `<ol>` containing `<li>`. Often issues like this is caused by incorrect html.

```
<ul class="my-items">
<li><textarea></textarea></li>
<li><textarea></textarea></li>
<li><textarea></textarea></li>
<li><textarea></textarea></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
 $( ".my-items" ).sortable();
```

If you like to disable text-selection inside the list-item, do it on all text-elements. Not the textarea. Wrap text in p, span, div and call disableSelection() only on those elements.

It's also a good practice to validate html before troubleshooting scripts. I prefer the http://validator.w3.org/ service.